# Is the last inserted data available when SELECTing from a distributed table of *MergeTree family?

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-client

Can I be sure that the last inserted data is available in a `distrubuted` table (based on tables from `*ReplicatedMergeTree` family) after `clickhouse` return control after an `INSERT` request or NOT?

Say, I have a local table like the next one:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_namespace.local_table ON CLUSTER my_cluster
(
    `field1` UInt32,
    `field2` String,
    `timestamp` DateTime,
    `array_field` Array(String)
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(timestamp)
ORDER BY field
SETTINGS index_granularity = 128
```

And a distributed table which is used as a source for `SELECT` (connected to the local above):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
    my_namespace.distributed_table 
ON CLUSTER 
    my_cluster 
AS 
    my_namespace.distributed_table
ENGINE = Distributed('my_claster', 'my_namespace', 'distributed_table', sipHash64(field1))
```

After inserting some amount of data to the distributed table (`my_namespace.distributed_table` ) I'd like to remove some `rows` with `ALTER` and a `subquery` with `SELECT`:

```
ALTER TABLE 
    my_namespace.distributed_table
DELETE WHERE 
    concat(toString(field1), toString(timestamp)) not in 
    (
        SELECT 
            concat(toString(field1), toString(max(timestamp))) 
        FROM 
            my_namespace.distributed_table
                GROUP BY
                    field1
    )
```

I suppose the inserted `rows` will be available when `DELETING`.

Can it be inserted at some replica(s) only and can it be not available immediately for `SELECT` queries like the `query` above?

Comment: 1) `ALTER TABLE DELETE` -- is an admin operation. You cannot use it on daily basis.

Comment: 2) CH is eventual database. You should not "be sure". It's the wrong question.

Comment: 3) insert_distributed_sync, insert_quorum

Comment: @DennyCrane What does mean "Clickhouse is eventual database"? Probably you joke.

Comment: ? But CH consistency ( replication , distributed inserts, mutations ) are eventual.

Comment: @DennyCrane It seems not eventual, it seems unstable by time.

Comment: @DennyCrane Thank you! Of course, if we have a distributed system then some is eventual, you are right.